# Creating DEM from contours in GRASS QGIS?

Tags: qgis

GRASS GIS Plugin - there are several modules you can use (v.surf.* and r.surf.*). You need convert your shapefile into a GRASS database to use the GRASS modules in QGIS.

I tried this option but its not processing.
what should i do?
Is their any other way in SAGA QGIS or something else please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [GRASS GIS: Contour lines to DEM](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM).

You can use all the cited commands (apart from  r.surf.nnbathy) directly from the Processing Toolbox without the need to convert your shapefile into a GRASS database